# "admin.firestore.collection is not a function" at react firebase - how to pass initiated admin object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a little cloud function that triggers, when someone is invited to a "project". It is supposed to save a notification in `/users/{id}/annotations`.

```
  import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
  import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

  import {sendAnnotation} from '../utils/AnnotationService'

  // Looks up whether an invited user is already registrated.
  // If yes: Sends an Email and leaves an annotation in /users/{id}/annotations
  // If no: Sends an Email and registers a ghost user with an annotation in 
  /users/{id}/annotations

   export default functions.firestore
  .document('/projects/{projectid}/invitations/{invitationId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.data()


    let email = data.email
    let sentBy = data.sentBy
    let createdAt = data.createdAt
    let invitedTo = context.params.projectid

    admin.firestore()
      .collection('users/')
      .where("email", "==", email)
      .get()
      .then((usersQuerySnapshot) => {
        if ( usersQuerySnapshot.empty ) {
          //Invited User not found in Database
          console.log('Invited User not registrated')

        } else {
          //Invited User found in Database
          usersQuerySnapshot.forEach( userSnapshot => {
            let userId = userSnapshot.id
            let payload = {
              type: 'projectInvitation',
              meta: {
                invitedTo: invitedTo,
                createdAt: createdAt,
                sentBy: sentBy,
                state: 'pending',
                expires: ''
              },
              isRead: 'false',
            }
            console.log(admin)
            sendAnnotation(admin, userId, payload)

          })
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  })`
```

This works all very well, no errors what so ever. The crucial part is 'sendAnnotation(admin, userId, payload)` defined like this:

```
export function sendAnnotation(admin, userId, payload) {
    console.log('Invitation sent to ' + userId + ' with payload: ' + JSON.stringify(payload))

    admin.firestore
      .collection(`/users/${userId}/annotations`)
      .add(payload)
      .catch( err => {
        console.log(err.message || err)
      })

  }
```

Here the firebase console prints `admin.firestore.collection is not a function`. Since the syntax of admin.firestore.collection is exactly like in the documentation i am wondering, if there is any problem with the passing of the initiated admin object.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two bits of code you show are not exactly the same.  The first time you use the admin SDK, you called it like this:

```
admin.firestore().collection(...)
```

The second time you use it, you called it like this:

```
admin.firestore.collection(...)
```

`admin.firestore` is a function, not a property, so you'll need to call it as a function.

Comment: Oh, that was it! Thank you!